# What is the bigOh or running time of the following algorithm

Tags: time, big-o, time-complexity

What is the running time of the following algorithm in bigO.

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=i;j<=n;j++){
        for(int k=j; k<=n;k++){
            for(int l=k; l<=n;l++){

                ...

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This algorithm seems to be n^4. Of course, from the theoretical perspective (without any compiler considerations).

Answer (score 2):

N^4. The fractional part doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

A formula for such a collection of dependent loops, can be inferred like the following:

[image]

Where **c** (constant) is the number of operations inside the innermost loop, **n** is the number of elements, and **r** is the number of nested loops.

In the question's case:

[image]

[image]

Another methodology, efficient but tedious, is to use Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

O(N^4) is the cost.

each for nested is N^
 so essentially N * N * N * N = N^4

CS610, Algorithm Development, NJIT.
My graduate coursework is actually coming in handy.

Comment: Working out orders of complexity is first year material normally?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was in first year some low level undergrad CS class they started it, then they reviewed it in beginning of grad school (CS610). Just wanted to highlight my grad school alma mater ;)

Answer (score 0):

my answer is O(N^4)...because there are four "for loops"..and it is easy to judge the runing time of this algo...thanks !